# Exist basis, simultaneously upper-triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be such that $\text{rank}(AB - BA) \le 1$. Does there exist a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with respect to which $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously upper-triangular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general truth provided that the underlying field $\mathbb F$ is algebraically closed. For a simple proof, see theorem 9.3.1 (pp.303-304) of Gohberg, Lancaster and Rodman, *Invariant Supspaces of Matrices with Applications*, SIAM, 2006.

Suppose $A$ is singular and $\operatorname{rank}(AB-BA)=1$. The main idea is that at least one of $\ker(A)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is an (nontrivial proper) invariant subspace of $B$. If this can be proved, the rest follows from mathematical induction.

In fact, if $\ker(A)$ is not an invariant subspace of $B$, then $Ax=0\ne ABx$ for some vector $x$. Hence $(AB-BA)x=ABx\ne0$, and $ABx$ spans the column space of the rank-one matrix $AB-BA$. So, for any vector $v$, we have $(AB-BA)v=cABx$ for some scalar $c$. Hence $BAv=ABv-cABx\in\operatorname{Im}(A)$, i.e. $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is an invariant subspace of $B$.$\ \blacksquare$

---

There are also some related results. E.g. $A,B$ are also triangulable if the field also has characteristic zero, $\operatorname{rank}(AB-BA)\le2$ and a further nilpotency condition is satisfied. See the following papers for some of them:

- Laffey (1980, p.196), [*Simultaneous triangularization of a pair of matrices whose commutator has rank two*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379580902402), Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 29:195-203 (1980),
- Laffey (1978), [*Simultaneous triangularization of matrices — low rank cases and the nonderogatory case*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087808817249?src=recsys),
- Robert M. Guralnick (1979), [*A note on pairs of matrices with rank one commutator*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087908817305).

Comment: he had more condition

Comment: @hctb Yes and no. Yes, for rank-2 commutators, I misread the result and more conditions are actually needed. No, for rank-1 commutators, we don't need any further conditions. See the first paragraph right after the first theorem on p.196 of Laffey (1980).